# Vim compiled with python3 but has('python') returns 0

Tags: installing, linux-ubuntu

I just followed these instructions to compile vim with python 3: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source

After the install I checked to see if I have python3:

```
vim --version | grep "python"
```

Which returned:

```
+python3/dyn
```

and

```
+python/dyn
```

But when I start vim and type one of the followinf commands, I get a `0`:

- `:echo has('python3/dyn')`
- `:echo has('python3')`
- `:echo has('python')`
- `:echo has('python/dyn')`

Has anyone had a similar problem?

EDIT:
Hey guys lots of helpful comments, I just wanted to say thanks and let you guys know what I did to solve this. I followed the instruction again from the first link I provided but this time I removed vim.tiny and instead of trying to get vim to support both python2 and python3, I just build with python3 support. This fixed it

Typing

```
python3 print("works")
```

in vim, shows `works`. Typing

```
echo has('python3')
```

gives me an output of `1` and finally

```
vim --version | grep python3
```

Gives me a value of `+python3`

Thanks guys for all the help and suggestions!!

Comment: Try running an actual Python command, e.g. `:python print "works"`; that's the best test (at least interactively; in a script I would prefer `has('python')`,which should work.

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, use pi-rho's PPA (https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev). It has vim built with dynamic Python/Python3 support.

Comment: It worked for me too!

Comment: I had same problem and solved it by configuring the Vim just using with Python3 but without Python.

Comment: `Sorry, the command is not available in this version` getting this error on vim 8.2 in Mac, what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected result.  There are no tests `has('python/dyn')` and `has('python3/dyn')`, only `has('python')` and `has('python3')`.

Comment: still does not help if I do has('python3') or has('python'), i still get a 0

Comment: The point is that you can't test for dynamic python with `has()` so… don't use `has()`.

Comment: @romainl Then why it is a documented feature that can be checked for with `has()` under [`:help feature-list`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#feature-list)?

Comment: `has('python')` returns `1` for `+python` *and* `+python/dyn`. Same thing for `has('python3')` and `+python3`/`+python3/dyn`. Also, `has('python/dyn')` and `has('python3/dyn')` always return `0`, whether the feature is there or not. Conclusion: either you can't use `has()` to determine if you have `+python[3]/dyn` or neither Sato Katsura nor me know how to format the argument properly.

Comment: Nope, my fault.  I was reading `:help +feature-list`, not `:help feature-list`.  The former specifies what shows up in `:version` while the latter shows what you can check with `has()`.

Comment: Although, it would be useful for Vim to support the `/dyn` checks, especially since `has('python')` loads the Python library, which means you then can't use `python3`, and vice-versa.

Comment: @jamessan If your script is prepared to use both then you probably also have a preference, and you should check for the preferred version first.  If your script isn't prepared to use both version then obviously you only need to check for the version you can use.  But IIRC you can actually use both in the same script, at least in recent versions of Vim. Either way, I have no word into what goes into Vim and what doesn't. _shrug_

Comment: @user1314272 If `has('python3')` and `has('python')` both return 0 then you found a bug, and you should report it to `vim_dev`. Complaining about it to here doesn't accomplish anything useful.

Comment: @SatoKatsura not necessarily. The required dll needs to be available and has to be loaded before it returns 1

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old, however, I want to share here what I found on [vim help page](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-en/if_pyth.html#has-python) after searching relating issue.

You can use `has('python3_dynamic')` to check if your vim has `+python3/dyn`, whereas `has('python3_compiled')` is only for `+python3`, not `+python3/dyn`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 2 times `has('python3_compiled')`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Sorry I made a mistake while copying from vim help page. The answer is now clear, hopefully.