# cannot source file when trying to make a vim pluggin with python3

Tags: vimscript, plugin-system

I recently updated my vim to have Python3 support. I was having trouble with it, but I eventually solved the problem that I described [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9606/2313). Now I am trying to make a vim plugin using python3 and I wrote a test file but when I try to do `source %` I get:

```
Error detected while processing /home/marv/Documents/vimPlugins/test/plugin/test.vim:
line    4:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: python import sys
line    5:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: python import vim
line    6:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: python sys.path.append(vim.eval('expand("<sfile>:h"
)'))
```

Here is all my code. 
FILE: test.vim

```
" --------------------------------
  " Add our plugin to the path
  " --------------------------------
  python import sys
  python import vim
  python sys.path.append(vim.eval('expand("<sfile>:h")'))

  " --------------------------------
  "  Function(s)
  " --------------------------------
  function! TemplateExample()
  python << endOfPython

  from test import test_example

  for n in range(5):
      print(test_example())

  endOfPython
  endfunction

  " --------------------------------
  "  Expose our commands to the user
  " --------------------------------
  command! Example call TemplateExample()
```

FILE: test.py

```
def test_example():
    return "Happy Hacking!"
```

again I have python3 working on this in vim doing `echo has ('python3')` returns a `1`.

Here is part of the output for `version`

```
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +dialog_con_gui  +job             +mouse_sgr       +rightleft       +user_commands
+arabic          +diff            +jumplist        -mouse_sysmouse  +ruby            +vertsplit
+autocmd         +digraphs        +keymap          +mouse_urxvt     +scrollbind      +virtualedit
+balloon_eval    +dnd             +lambda          +mouse_xterm     +signs           +visual
+browse          -ebcdic          +langmap         +multi_byte      +smartindent     +visualextra
++builtin_terms  +emacs_tags      +libcall         +multi_lang      +startuptime     +viminfo
+byte_offset     +eval            +linebreak       -mzscheme        +statusline      +vreplace
+channel         +ex_extra        +lispindent      +netbeans_intg   -sun_workshop    +wildignore
+cindent         +extra_search    +listcmds        +num64           +syntax          +wildmenu
+clientserver    +farsi           +localmap        +packages        +tag_binary      +windows
+clipboard       +file_in_path    +lua             +path_extra      +tag_old_static  +writebackup
+cmdline_compl   +find_in_path    +menu            +perl            -tag_any_white   +X11
+cmdline_hist    +float           +mksession       +persistent_undo -tcl             -xfontset
+cmdline_info    +folding         +modify_fname    +postscript      +termguicolors   +xim
+comments        -footer          +mouse           +printer         +terminfo        +xpm
+conceal         +fork()          +mouseshape      +profile         +termresponse    +xsmp_interact
+cryptv          +gettext         +mouse_dec       -python          +textobjects     +xterm_clipboard
+cscope          -hangul_input    +mouse_gpm       +python3         +timers          -xterm_save
+cursorbind      +iconv           -mouse_jsbterm   +quickfix        +title
+cursorshape     +insert_expand   +mouse_netterm   +reltime         +toolbar
```

anyone know why I get this error of "the command is not available in this version:"?

Comment: You get that error because the `:python` command actually isn't available in your Vim.  Please read: `:h python3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `:python foo` if you have `+python` and/or `+python/dyn`.
- Use `:python3 foo` if you have `+python3` and/or `+python/dyn`.

Since you only have `+python3` there's no reason whatsoever to expect `:python` to work.

See `:help python`.

Comment: I don't understand, please explain I am a total noob. I don't want to use python I want to use python3. How and where am I trying to use python and not python3?

Comment: *facepalm* sorry I see my obvious error